# How to get the value of element with selector

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

   height = $('#container-bottom:before').height();
   alert(height);

});
```

Alerts `null` (and I know the value is not `null` of course).

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle including some example html? In theory $.height should return a unit-less value of the height of the specified element.

Comment: @DravSloan Here's a link with the example 
http://jsfiddle.net/EFXMf/

Comment: There aren't any html elements before ...

Comment: Is there any reason for the css selector :before? Removing that from both the css and the jquery select seems to render the same output and give the expected value (200)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortuantely CCS pseudo-elements (like `:before`, `:after`) are not part of the DOM (although they're rendered as if they were) - thus they can't be manipulated with jQuery.

See: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks, well, after all I had to use a real element and that fixed the problem, instead of the pseudo element :before.